# Rails: Postgresql where with multiple conditions with join (polymorphic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, join

Hi guys here is my code:

```
class Tailor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :tailor_items
    has_many    :order_items

    [:collars, :sexes, :sleeves].each do |attribute|
        has_many    attribute, through: :tailor_items, source: :item, source_type: attribute.to_s.classify

    end
 end

class TailorItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to        :tailor
  belongs_to        :item, polymorphic: true
end

class Collar < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

What I need to do is this:
For a given shirt I need to select a tailor. A shirt can have a collar, male/female or a certain type of sleeve. Some tailors can make all collars but only a few sleeves, others can make only male stuff, etc.
The priority doesnt matter for this example. The idea is that I end up with 1 tailor.

I tried this:

```
tailors = Tailor.joins(:tailor_items).where("(item_id = ? and item_type = ?)",1,"Collar")
if tailors.count > 1
  tailors.where("(item_id = ? and item_type = ?)",2,"Sleeve")
  if tailors.count > 1
     # and so forth.
  end
end
```

But I never get a row back.
If I say:

```
Tailor.find(1).tailor_items
```

I get two results (sudo code for simplicity)

```
<id: 1, item_type: "Collar"><id:2, item_type:"Sleeve">
```

and for second tailor:

```
Tailor.find(2).tailor_items
```

I get two results (sudo code for simplicity)

```
<id: 1, item_type: "Collar"><id:3, item_type:"Sleeve">
```

but when I try to chain them in the query its no worky...
Not even if I put it all in one where:

```
Tailor.where("(item_id = 1 and item_type = 'Collar') and (item_id = 2 and item_type = 'Sleeve')")
```

I still get 0 results.

```
Tailor.where("item_id = 1 and item_type = 'Collar'") returns: Tailor #1
Tailor.where("item_id = 2 and item_type = 'Sleeve'") returns: Tailor #1
```

but together they return nothing.

```
Tailor Load (0.0ms) SELECT "tailors".* FROM "tailors" INNER
JOIN "tailor_items" ON "tailor_items"."tailor_id" = "tailors"."id" WHERE ((tailo
r_items.item_id = 1 and tailor_items.item_type = 'Collar') and (tailor_items.ite
m_id = 2 and tailor_items.item_type = 'Sleeve'))
```

I am confused..

Thanks for your help.

I run:
Win XP
Postgresql
Rails 3.2.2

PS: The only thing missing to make this complete after a polymorphic join is a bit of XML. :P Otherwise its just not enterprise-y enough..

EDIT:
Implementing Rob di Marcos scope, I get this SQL:

```
SELECT "tailors".* FROM "tailors" WHERE 
(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tailor_items WHERE tailor_items.item_id = 1 and tailor_items.item_type = 'Collar')) 
AND (exists(select * from tailor_items where tailor_items.item_id = 2 and tailor_items.item_type = 'Sleeve'))
```

This returns
2 tailors instead of only tailor 1 who can do both (while tailor 2 cant do sleeve #2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the where needs to match on two rows.  I generally will use sub-queries to test for this.  So something like

```
Tailor.where("exists (select 'x' from tailor_items where 
         tailor_id = tailors.id and tailor_items.item_id = ? and 
         tailor_items.item_type=?)", 1, 'Collar').
       where("exists (select 'x' from tailor_items where 
         tailor_id = tailors.id and tailor_items.item_id = ? and 
         tailor_items.item_type=?)", 2, 'Sleeve')
```

In this example, I have one sub-query for each tailor item I am looking for.  I could easily make this a scope on Tailor like:

```
class Tailor
  # ....
  scope :with_item, lambda{ |item_id, item_type | 
      where("exists (select 'x' from tailor_items where 
     tailor_id = tailors.id and tailor_items.item_id = ? and 
     tailor_items.item_type=?)", item_id, item_type)
     }
```

and then be able to chain my Tailor request

```
Tailor.with_item(1, 'Collar').with_item(2, 'Sleeve')
```

Comment: ok I did get your scope to work, there was a ) missing at the end. But the problem now is that it returns too many results. Tailor1 has Collar1,Sleeve1 and Tailor2 has Collar1, Sex1. If I do: Tailor.with_item(1, "Collar").with_item(1, "Sex") it returns Tailor1 and Tailor2. But I only want Tailor 2.

Comment: Can you look in the log and post the generated SQL for the select.

Comment: I edited my question to include the SQL. Thanks for your help.

Comment: oops, I see the issue, you are missing the part of the scope "tailor_id = tailors.id" that limits the exists query to only items associated with the tailor.

Comment: You won the internets for today my friend. Thank you very much for your help :)